# Apacheのサービス起動・停止・再起動を簡易にしたい

Tags: apache

超初心者っぽい質問で申し訳ありません。
先日WindowsServer2012R2にApache2.4をインストールすることに成功しました。インターネットの記事、https://techacademy.jp/magazine/1846 を参考に行い
特別なインストーラ（msi）を実行したわけではなく、ただ単にzipを解凍として該当サービスを登録した感じです．．．

====質問====
インターネット上の別の記事で、Windows版というものがあり、そちらに従ったインストールを行えば、サービスの起動・停止を行うユーティリティが同梱されている雰囲気に受けてとれます。
当方は先に記載した方法でインストールを行ったからか、サービスの停止・起動を行う際に
Windowsの管理ツール/サービスメニュから指示をしなければならない状況です。

皆様　同様なのでしょうか？簡易にワンタッチで行うことはできないのでしょうか？該当コマンド（httpd -k start）のbatファイルを自分で作っておく、というのが常識なら　それはそれで納得しますが、皆がそうしているのかな？？と思ったわけで

お手すきの方　よろしくお願い申し上げます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> サービスの起動・停止を行うユーティリティが同梱されている

これは、タスクトレイに常駐する**Apache Service Monitor**のことかと思われます。
提示されているURLから取得したバイナリでは、下記のものが該当します。

Apache24\bin\ApacheMonitor.exe

オフィシャルドキュメントでの言及は下記リンク先くらいしか見つけられませんでしたが、使用法については、ファイル名 "ApacheMonitor.exe" で検索すれば日本語で解説されている方々のサイトもヒットするかと思います。

- [Running Apache as a Service : Using Apache HTTP Server on Microsoft Windows - Apache HTTP Server Version 2.4](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/platform/windows.html#winsvc)

Comment: ご見解をありがとうございました。まさにこれです。PHP.iniを編集した際などに適時サービスを再起動したい子尾があるので、こちらを今後利用していきたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

webサーバの使用目的や運用ルールにもよりますが、サーバ(サービス)類は基本的に一度起動させたら滅多なことでは停止しませんし、再起動もApacheの場合ならhttpd.confなどの設定ファイルを変更した時のみでしょう。
Windowsのサービスとして登録したのであれば、管理ツールからApacheのサービスを「自動起動」にしておけば手動で立ち上げる必要はありません(OS起動時にバックグラウンドで勝手に立ち上がる)。